# Cannot see issue with "Incorrect syntax near ','." Error message?

Tags: sql, insert, message

I'm trying to insert less than 1,000 rows of data with an `INSERT INTO` statement, but cannot see what is wrong.

I was able to get this to work on my home SQL server, but when I emulated this at work, it didn'y work.

When I put in one row of data into the insert (either one of the two given below), it works. When I comma-separate the rows and insert them simultaneously, I get "Incorrect syntax near ','" error message.

Any help/suggestions? Is there a limitation, either on the account used or the number of character (e.g. 255) that can be parsed through?

One line works (each one individually), but both together don't:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.NEW_BUSINESS_HISTORY ([A],[B],[C],[D],[E],[F],[G],[H],[J],[K],[L],[M],[N],[O],[P],[Q],[R],[S],[T],[U],[V],[W],[A1],[A2],[Product],[Product_Category],[Record_Type],[Region],[Reporting_Date],[Sales_Desk],[Sales_Desk_Head],[Z1],[Z2],[Z3],[Z4],[Z5],[Z6],[Z7],[Z8],[B1],[B2],[B3],[B4],[B5],[SharePoint Path],[Status],[Unique_Identifier],[Age1],[Age2],[Age3],[Age4],[Age5],[Age6],[Age7],[Age8],[Age9],[Age10],[Age11],[Age12],[Age13],[Age14],[Age15],[Age16],[Age17],[Age18])

VALUES
(NULL,NULL,NULL,'ACME Corp',NULL,NULL,NULL,'L','Web data','2012-09-19',NULL,'Not Assigned',NULL,NULL,'IB',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'John Doe','1234567',NULL,NULL,NULL,'France','2014-12-31',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Blank',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'PENDING IN PROGRESS','ABC123456',' 120',NULL,NULL,'833',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Sep',NULL,'2012'),

(NULL,NULL,NULL,'ACME Ltd',NULL,NULL,NULL,'L','Web data','2012-09-19',NULL,'Not Assigned',NULL,NULL,'IB',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'John Doe','1234567',NULL,NULL,NULL,'France','2014-12-31',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Blank',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'PENDING IN PROGRESS','ABC123456',' 120',NULL,NULL,'833',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,'Sep',NULL,'2012');
```

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Looks like MS SQL: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms174335.aspx

Comment: But what exact version?

Comment: At a guess, you're talking to a 2005 or older server. [INSERT](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174335(v=sql.100).aspx): "SQL Server 2008 introduces the Transact-SQL row constructor (also called a table value constructor) to specify multiple rows in a single INSERT statement. The row constructor consists of a single VALUES clause with multiple value lists enclosed in parentheses and separated by a comma"

Answer (score -2):

Do you use this syntax?

The `?` are there because I used an Example from Java which works with PreparedStatements.

```
String query = "INSERT INTO chatmessage (Chatroom_Id, Date, Employee_Id, Message) VALUES (?,?,?,?)";
```

Maybe you should try to commit your inserts.

Comment: Hi Mansouritta, yes I am using this syntax. My insert statement is in  format:

INSERT INTO [Table] (Field1, Fiel2, Field3)
VALUES
(a,b,c),
(d,e,f);

When I do:
INSERT INTO [Table] (Field1, Fiel2, Field3)
VALUES
(a,b,c)

OR 
INSERT INTO [Table] (Field1, Fiel2, Field3)
VALUES
(d,e,f)

both work.

But when I do 
INSERT INTO [Table] (Field1, Fiel2, Field3)
VALUES
(a,b,c),
(d,e,f);

which should work (works at hm, but not at work), I get error message that the "," after (a,b,c) is "incorrect syntax".

Can't see what I'm doing wrong or what the limitation might be (account or chars in string, etc)?

Comment: hmm
try to add a space before and after. so:
VALUES (a,b,c) , (d,e,f)